# Timer vs Background Services, Battery, Xamarin c#

Tags: android, xamarin, service, timer, background

I need to do some computations every 15 minutes no matter if the app is in the foreground or in the background.

Firstly, I have implemented a more complex Background Services with a Pending Intent, Receivers and an Alarm Manager that triggers a function every 15 minutes. However, I realised I could achieve the same results by using a simple Timer.

I am programming in C# Xamarin.

I am just wondering which version would be more efficient and which one consumes the least of battery power?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`AlarmManager` is a sufficient solution. It is the traditional solution for doing work on a period basis. However the caveat is that people misuse it and it impacts the battery heavily. There are other problems with it, but I will not discuss that here.

I would recommend using `JobScheduler` for more efficient background work. The `JobScheduler` will handle `wakefulness` via it's own implemented `WakeLock` and provide us an API that we can specify certain criteria to control what we need to fulfill our tasks (Network, etc). If it cannot meet our criteria, we will have a callback that we can then figure out how to match it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html